# hostingEnvironment.ApplicationID property

Tags: c#, iis

From what I have read on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.applicationid(v=vs.110).aspx), this property returns the unique identifier of the application. But what does that actually mean?

Is it a sort of ID created for that application on IIS?

Or is it a random ID generated on different sessions of the application? Or something else and i'm grasping the concept completely wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the unique identifier in the IIS metabase assigned to each application.

Usually it would look something like:

```
/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT
```

When `1` in this case is the number you'll see in the "Sites" panel in your IIS manager:

[image]

Comment: And this id remains the same if I upgrade the IIS version (for example from 6 to 7 or 7 to 8)?

Comment: Not necessarily, but you can always edit the metabase / configuration and the ID.